# Python variable is not being incremented

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, increment

I am trying to make a simple calculator using python (tkinter GUI). However, when I try and increment my pointer variable, it does not work. From what I could figure out, this was caused because my pointer variable was not global and I did not declare it as a global variable. But even after I did that, it is still not working. Can someone explain why?

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator (Simple)")

entrybox = Entry(root, width = 40, borderwidth= 5)
entrybox.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

global pointer
pointer = 0

def button_entry(num):
    pointer += 1
    number = entrybox.get() + num
    entrybox.delete(0, END)
    entrybox.insert(0, number)
    print(pointer)
```

Comment: `global pointer` should be inside `button_entry`, not with the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global pointer` should be inside `button_entry` inside the function on 1st line.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put global pointer in the function, not outside, because it says to python interpreter that you need to use a variable that is not described in this function and it's in global scope

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator (Simple)")

entrybox = Entry(root, width = 40, borderwidth= 5)
entrybox.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

pointer = 0

def button_entry(num):
    global pointer
    pointer += 1
    number = entrybox.get() + num
    entrybox.delete(0, END)
    entrybox.insert(0, number)
    print(pointer)
```